# Recovering a linked list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a linked list that has been stored out of order in an array and the information about the original order is preserved by storing with each element the index of the next element.

For example,

```
[c;3][b;0][a;1][d;4]
```

Here `[c;3]` means that `c` is followed by `d` (stored at 3); `[b;0]` means that `b` is followed by `c` (stored at 0), and so on.  The out of bound index `4` in `[d;4]` means that `d` is the last element.

I am looking for an algorithm to extract the original linked list order, `abcd` in the example, from such an array.

The last element always comes last (already at the correct place) and the algorithm may use this fact.

To clarify the question, let me reformulate it in terms of Python data structures.

I have a list of 2-tuples where the second element in each tuple is an integer that defines the traversal order through the list.  The value of the integer is the index of the next tuple to be traversed.  For example, given a list

```
[('c', 3), ('b', 0), ('a', 1), ('d', 4)]
```

the traversal order is

```
[2, 1, 0, 3]
```

or `('a', 1)` -> `('b', 0)` -> `('c', 3)` -> `('d', 4)`.  How can I write a function that given a list of 2-tuples described above would find the traversal order.

Here is a possible Python solution:

```
def order(x):
    nexts = [n for _, n in x]
    prevs = [-1] * (len(a) + 1)
    for i, n in enumerate(nexts):
        prevs[n] = i
    trav = []
    i = prevs[-1]
    for _ in x:
        trav.append(i)
        i = prevs[i]
    return trav[::-1]
```

Given the example data

```
>>> a = [('c', 3), ('b', 0), ('a', 1), ('d', 4)]
```

this function produces the expected result

```
>>> order(a)
[2, 1, 0, 3]
>>> [a[i] for i in order(a)]
[('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can probably treat this a topological sort problem, but since I know that the ordering is complete, there should be a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

The head is the element that has nothing pointing to it. You can walk through once and keep track of what has nothing pointing to it, then walk through again to print them out in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

What about sorting the array itself?

C is followed by [3], so swap c with [2] (element before [3]), and continue the same for each. But you'll have to keep track of original index and swapped/latest index for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the head of the linked list in O(n) time and space by looking for whatever element isn't pointed at.

Alternatively, sort by index pointed at in ascending order such that NULL is greater than any index. This can definitely be done in O(n log n) time and O(1) space; you can also use a linear sorting algorithm since the indices are bounded fairly well. There may be in-place variants of linear sorts; something to check.

Answer (score 0):

So you have this `[c;3][b;0][a;1][d;NULL]` and you want to rearrange to `[a][b][c][d]`.

It's given that the last item in the array contains the tail of the list. So you could build the list backward using an O(n^2) algorithm that's similar to selection sort.

The general idea, in pseudo code, is:

```
new_list = new array[a.length];
int pass = a.length-1;
new_list[pass] = a[a.length-1];

while (pass > 0)
{
    for (j = 0; j < a.length-1; j++)
    {
        if (a[j].index == pass)
        {
            new_list[pass] = a[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    --pass;
}
```

That should work, although it's not very efficient. But it'd be fine for small lists if you don't call it very often.

There's a faster way that uses a dictionary and is just slightly more difficult to code. The idea is that you store the item's position as the key, and its predecessor as the value. If you don't have the item's predecessor yet, you store -1. So for this example, you look at the first item, `[c;3]`. You don't know its predecessor, so you store `{0,-1}` in the dictionary. Then look in the dictionary to see if you already have an entry for '3'. You don't, so you skip forward to the item at index 3 in the array, which is `[d,NULL]`. Its predecessor is 0, so you add `{3,0}` to the dictionary.

At this point, you don't have a successor, so you go back to the last place you were in your sequential scan and go to the next item: `[b;0]`. You don't know its predecessor, so you store `{1,-1}` in the dictionary. This item's successor is 0, which you already have in the dictionary. So you update the entry to `{0,1}`, and proceed with your forward scan. You don't know the predecessor of `[a;1]`, so you add `{2,-1}` to your dictionary. You already have an entry for 1 in your dictionary, so you update it to `{1,2}`. You move forward to the last entry, see that 4 is already in your dictionary, and you're done.

Your dictionary contains:

```
{0,1},{3,0}{1,2}{2,-1}
```

Since you know that 3 is the end of the list, you start there in the dictionary and build the ordered sequence backwards by following the predecessor links. You know you're done when you reach the entry that has a predecessor of -1.

Worst case, this makes 3*n passes over each item: twice in the scan of the array, and once when following links in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first sort the letters and then find the numbers that go with them:

```
def order(tuples, index_of_value):
   aim = []

   # Loop through sorted letters
   l = [i[index_of_value] for i in tuples] # Find the nth of each tuple
   for i in sorted(l):
      #Find the number that goes with it and append
      correct = [j for j in tuples if j[0] == i]
      first_num = correct[0][0]
      second_num = correct[0][1]
      aim.append(tuple((first_num, second_num))) # Turn back into tuple and append

   return aim

a = [('c', 3), ('b', 0), ('a', 1), ('d', 4)]
print(order(a, 0))

>>> [('a', 1), ('b', 0), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In order to have a linked list, you must have a pointer to its head (beginning). To find the head in this situation, iterate over the entire array once until you know which node is not pointed to by any other node. Then all you need to do is follow the pointer at each node until you reach NULL.

Comment: Well...the question was pretty generic. I can't really give code to match with code that doesn't exist.

Comment: Finding the head is part of the problem.

Comment: Ah interesting...Well if you don't have a pointer to the head, how do you even know where in memory your data is?

Comment: The data comes in an array.  In the example that I provided, the head element is `[a;1]` stored at index 2.

Comment: Ok. could you edit the question to reflect that? Its not clear.

Comment: Is it better now?